# Icon for collapsing/expanding left side panel on tablet

Tags: icons, iconography, tablet

I'm struggling to find a good icon to represent to users that while reading an article or something similar, they can click a small icon to reveal a left side panel to show additional options.

I've seen the full screen icon with arrows pointing outward in all directions for expand and pointing inward for collapse, but I'm looking for something more specific to show that the panel will pop out from the left and it can be collapsed as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The Opera browser uses this icon for exactly that purpose:

[image]

And of course with the corresponding one for close:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really think you've answered your own question.  If you've seen the same thing everyone else has seen to expand and retract a side panel then most likely that is the best option since it will be immediately recognizable. [CNN MONEY](http://money.cnn.com/) uses something like this to change to a tablet view.